How can I react to a measurement events in Autodesk Forge Viewer
I want to add an Event Listener to my Forge Viewer implementation to output any measurements that were taken as it is described here Get the measured value in a side note.
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MeasureCommon.Events.MEASUREMENT_COMPLETED_EVENT, (event)=> { /* HERE YOUR CODE */ });
I tried the snippet but I can't find any Events in MeasureCommon:
No Events in MeasureCommon
Maybe there was a change in the API. Can you help?
